# How to reference package added by Bower?

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio

In VS.NET 2015, I've added a reference in bower.json for angularjs.  This caused the angularjs package to be downloaded, which I can see in the Bower folder.

However, I'm not able to execute any angularjs code.  I do have an ng-app in the HTML tag.  If I add a CDN reference to the angularjs library, it works fine.

What am I missing to use the package downloaded by Bower?

Comment: you either need to hardcode reference to `bower_components` or use `gulp/grunt` & do `wiredep` to get angular in your index.html file

Answer (score 7):

what are you missing is referencing the downloaded libraries in bower_components folder in your index.html.

For example let's say you added `restangular` to bower. the library while reside in `./bower_components/restangular` so in your index.html ( your SPA). you will reference it like this :

```
    <script src="../bower_components/restangular/dist/restangular.js"></script>
```

Beware sometimes you should add all the library main files ( js and css), for that you need to check the value of the `main` attribute included in the `bower.json` of the library . for our example in `bower.json` in   `../bower_components/restangular/` we have:

`"main": "./dist/restangular.js",`

In a the file .bowerrc you may define the directory for the downaloaded libraries in my example it will be bower_components.

In your .csproj file add the

```
    <Content Include="bower_components/restangular/dist/restangular.js" />
```

Use can see this [example](https://github.com/ryanwischkaemper/gulpBowerAngularASP.Net/blob/44a7d16d90dbbe3fed727bfaebd8edaccd2c086a/AngularApp/AngularApp.csproj)

Comment: Seems setting that path is completely disconnected from VS.NET.  "~" is actually the root in wwwroot.  So I can't use that.  I have tried "../" but that doesn't work.  I don't get any intellisense help.  I'm guessing Angular isn't work because of path issues.  But I'm not sure what path it wants. The question is: How do you reference something not in wwwroot?

Comment: @4thSpace Could you add your project directory hierarchy?

Answer (score 1):

Since more than likely for production deployment you won't be deploying things in bower_components directory, I suggest you setup a **gulp** or **grunt** task to copy all the JavaScript that you are going to use and probably minify and concat / bundle them into a folder in wwwroot like /lib or /js or whatever your convention is going to be and add a `script` tag pointing to that bundled version.  There is a decent [walkthrough](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/2-675) by Mads Kristensen from the recent Build event that you might want to look at. He demoed all the things you would probably need to get your app running.